# How to work react-native app even app is background or closed?

Tags: react-native

*I want my app work even closed or on background. I found this on web*

> react-native-background-task

*I used this but it works every in  7m30s . But  I want work my app always even app off. I mean I want to get app location in every second.*

**I used this :**

```
BackgroundTask.define(() => {

  navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
    console.log(position.coords.latitude);
    var lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude);
    var lng = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude);

      console.log("lat :",lat);
      console.log("lng :",lng);
});

  BackgroundTask.finish()
})

export default class App extends Component {

componentDidMount(){
  BackgroundTask.schedule();
}
```

How to do this ?

Comment: are you using expo?

Comment: No I am not using expo

Comment: its android or iOS?

Comment: i suggest you to use `https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android.html`

Comment: @AkshayMulgavkar android bro

Comment: why do u need it every second, it should just listen location change and then update, where are few gps modules for this purpose or create by self

Comment: how to I do this when location is changed ? @NeriusJok

Comment: react-native-background-geolocation maybe use this

Comment: I used that but it didnt help me